# WPF tooltip conditional

Tags: wpf, binding, tooltip

I have a `Textblock` within a Grid and has a `ToolTip` which should display the "tooltip" binding but if it is `Null` or `Empty` it should display "name" binding.

How can I achieve this in the XAML?

`<TextBlock Margin="3" TextAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ToolTip="{Binding Tooltip}" Text="{Binding Name}"/>`

Comment: XAML is for display not logic, if you need logic it should be in your view model, however you can use a PriorityBinding or multibinding

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `Style` with one or two `DataTriggers` that binds the `ToolTip` property to the `Name` source property only if the `Tooltip` source property returns `null` or an emtpy `string`:

```
<TextBlock Margin="3" TextAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                   Text="{Binding Name}">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Tooltip}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Tooltip}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Tooltip}" Value="">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the String is `NULL`

Create MultiValueConverter and declare as a static Resources:

```
<local:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
```

Your Converter Class should look like this:

```
public class MyConverter: IMultiValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
        string tooltip = values.ElementAtOrDefault(0) as string,
           name = values.ElementAtOrDefault(1) as string;
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tooltip))            
            return tooltip;            
        else            
            return name;                        
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
 }
```

And Your TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="12" Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding MyName}">
      <TextBlock.ToolTip>
           <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource NameConverter}">
               <Binding Path="Tooltip" IsAsync="True"/>
               <Binding Path="MyName"/>
           </MultiBinding>
      </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: wont work as he wants to bind multiple values, so needs a MultiBinding or PriorityBinding

Comment: I want to display one tooltip only - if the "tooltip"binding value is null or empty then display "name" binding value...don't need multibinding

Comment: @MaiurLaximidas what name you want to display when value is null

Comment: if both string are null then nothing to be displayed

Comment: @MaiurLaximidas you want it to bind to the Tooltip and Bind to the Name, you then want to pick which one to display based on the values

Comment: yes example if "Tooltip" has a value then display it else display whatever "name" has even if it null

Answer (score 2):

from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753174(v=vs.110).aspx)

PriorityBinding in Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) works by specifying a list of bindings. The list of bindings is ordered from highest priority to lowest priority. If the highest priority binding returns a value successfully when it is processed then there is never a need to process the other bindings in the list. It could be the case that the highest priority binding takes a long time to be evaluated, the next highest priority that returns a value successfully will be used until a binding of a higher priority returns a value successfully.

an example would look like this

```
<StackPanel>
    <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding ShowTooltip, Mode=TwoWay}" >toggle</ToggleButton>
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.ToolTip>
            <PriorityBinding>
                <Binding Path="ToolTipSometimes" Mode="OneWay"/>
                <Binding Path="Name" Mode="OneWay"/>
            </PriorityBinding>
        </TextBlock.ToolTip>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

where A binding returns a value successfully if:

- The path to the binding source resolves successfully.
- The value converter, if any, is able to convert the resulting value.
- The resulting value is valid for the target property.

Using a MultiBinding it could be done like this

```
<TextBlock >
    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
        <MultiBinding>
            <MultiBinding.Converter>
                <local:NullCleanup/>
            </MultiBinding.Converter>
            <Binding Path="ToolTip" Mode="OneWay"/>
            <Binding Path="Text" Mode="OneWay" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

with this as the converter

```
public class NullCleanup : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values.Aggregate((r, o) => r ?? o);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

However you can just put the logic in your VM

```
    private string _Tooltip;

    public string Tooltip;
    {
        get { return _Tooltip; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Tooltip, value,()=>RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ToolTipCleaned))); }
    }

    public string ToolTipCleaned => Tooltip ?? Name;
```

Comment: doesn't quite work for what i want to achieve...what determines a value is returned successfully? My requirement is if 1st binding returns null check second binding and display it even if the value is null....

Comment: I was hoping there would be something like ToolTip="{Binding Tooltip ?? Binding Name}

Comment: XAML stands for eXtensable Application Markup Language, as such it is in the same category as HTML it doesn't include preprocessing like ASP, Razor, or PHP

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by using by using TooltipOpening as follows:-

```
<TextBlock Margin="3" TextAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ToolTip="" ToolTipOpening="TextBlock_ToolTipOpening"  Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="470" />
```

Then in the "TextBlock_ToolTipOpening" method I applied my check as follows:-

```
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(stf.Tooltip))
    {
       t.ToolTip = stf.Tooltip;
    }
    else
    {
        t.ToolTip = stf.Name;
    }
```

It works as expected - thanks to all for your contributions...wouldn't have worked this out without your help.